# Installed CentOS on unallocated space for dual boot with Windows 10 and now CentOS cannot see Window 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, centos-7

I have a Window 10 laptop.  To install CentOS 7 on it, I shrunk the **C drive** (that is the only drive I saw).  This gave me 100+ GB **unallocated** space.  I went ahead and installed CentOS.  After reboot, I do not see Windows 10 as an option to boot in the menu.

What did I do wrong? Is there a way to recover form it and see Windows 10?

Comment: People usually install Windows as the last option. The Boot Menu has been overwritten by the CentOS Installer. You should seek a Software Utility that is able to rewrite the Master Boot Record in order to allow Windows to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Windows wasn't detected before installation. Boot into your CentOS installation and run these two commands:

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

If it says "command not found", replace update-grub with grub-mkconfig. You may have to install os-prober before doing this with

```
sudo yum install os-prober
```

If all else fails, you can add a custom entry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` that says this:

On BIOS systems: (replace n with 
Windows partition number)

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(hd0,n)
    chainloader +1
}
```

On UEFI systems (replace n with EFI partition number)

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    set root=(hd0,n)
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Depending on where your bootloader is in the EFI partition, the location can change for the EFI entry.

Run `sudo grub-mkconfig` after and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an experienced Linux user.  I am simply listing what I did to get this to work for me.  This was mostly trial and error based.  I am not recommending this one way or another. There may be proper way to resolve the problem. @Varun Narravula's reply may be more appropriate.  Note that I am using Legacy/BIOS.

I tried commands in the following order:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

then

```
os-prober
```

os-prober did not return anything.

Then I tried to see if I could mount the NTFS systems.

To do that I needed to install ntfs-3g.  But for ntfs-3g, EPEL Repo is a prerequisite.

Please refer to the following:

https://www.tecmint.com/how-do-i-access-or-mount-windows-ntfs-partition-in-linux/

I installed EPEL Repo on CentOS 7.x

```
yum search epel-release
yum info epel-release
yum install epel-release
```

(I did not actually run a yum update)

Then installed ntfs-3g

```
yum -y install ntfs-3g
```

Then

```
yum install fuse
modprobe fuse
```

I could see the NTFS file systems with

```
fdisk -l
```

(I did not actually mount the NTFS systems.) After this, I ran

```
os-prober
```

This did list Windows 10.  Final step, I ran again

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Not sure if the last step was necessary.  When I rebooted my machine Windows 10 option was available.  I am not sure if the steps I did related to mounting made any difference.